# Problem while browsing

Tags: firefox, freeze, browser

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my PC with 2+ Ghz processing speeds and 4gb RAM. While I'm browsing on using Firefox, the browser suddenly gets dim and then bright. It happened multiple times. While it happens, I cannot open a new tab or close the existing ones(to say, the browser freezes). Is it a problem with the software or with my PC ? Did anyone face similar problem ?

Comment: Is this happening with specific pages or at random? It can happen when a script on a page is not responding for example.

Comment: Facebook was open and I was searching on google.

Comment: Is it a returning phenomena? With the same site(s)?. A dimmed window is a "normal" thing when an (any) application "is in trouble".

Comment: It happened at different times with different sites opened. I don't think it happened always with same sites. The window turned to grey and then bright. May be the problem is with Firefox as per the two other answers I got.

Comment: Why don't you check other browsers like Chrome & Opera so that you can figure out whether the problem is with the browser itself or Ubuntu.... And hey have you checked out the links given below?

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting Firefox...
Try the links given below.

[Reset Firefox to its default state](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-to-fix-most-problems)
[Firefox Slow/Hangs](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox/fix-problems/slowness-or-hanging)

Answer (score 0):

Relax, This is a feature in ubuntu. Everytime your comp becomes unresponsive, it dims ( becomes greyish in colour).

Try not opening many tabs that are active. This should reduce the load on the cpu. Try removing any extra add-ons in the preference menu if any.

I presonally experience the same while launching ADT(eclipse) for a brief 2 or 3 seconds but is goes away after that.

Also, update firefox and other packages. run the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```